# Does IQueryable.First accepts a delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, iqueryable

Why does this code work?

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("foo");

IQueryable<string> query = list.AsQueryable(); 
var test = query.First((Func<string,bool>)(s => { return s.Contains("foo"); }));
```

I thought IQueryable.First accepts only an Expression. Why is it accepting a delegate in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IQueryable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, 
    IQueryable
```

So your method is actually a call to `Enumerable.First` and not `Queryable.First`.

You can see that when looking at method list at [`IQueryable<T>` documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx):

[image]

Comment: If I had not used a cast, I would have gotten an error. Is it because it is trying to convert the lambda into an Expression instead of a delegate?

Comment: What do you mean with *I would have gotten an error*? What cast are you referring to? The cast to `IQueryable<string>` or to `Func<string, bool>`?

Comment: The cast to `Func<string,bool>`. Without it, I get an error.

Comment: That's because the compiler is matching your call to an extension method of `IQueryable`, which expects an `Expression<Func<string, bool>>`, but expression trees cannot be created from a function body. The cast hints the compiler to choose the `IEnumerable` extension method which instead expects `Func<string, bool>` as parameter.